Unable to make post__not_in work correctly
I have a CPT with a custom taxonomy, "accommodatie", so I wrote a script to look for other related posts that are also in the same taxonomy. Unfortunately I have not been able to exclude the current post and I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.
posts_per_page does not work either, it just shows all posts in that taxonomy. Tried a dozen slight variations of this code but unable to make anything that works. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
<?php
  $accotype=get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'accommodatie');
        
  foreach ( $accotype as $parent_accotype ) {
    if ($parent_accotype->parent == 0) {
      $parent_accotype_value = $parent_accotype->term_taxonomy_id;
    }
  }
                
  $params = array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'taxonomy' => 'accommodatie',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms' => $parent_accotype_value,
        ),
      ),
    );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $params );

  if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="flex-container">';
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<div clas="flex_accom">';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $_post->ID ) ) {echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $_post->ID, 'medium' );}
        echo '<h4>' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
     echo '</div>';
   }

  wp_reset_postdata();      
?>

You can see the code in action on the staging site here:
https://staging.op-wintersport.nl/bestemmingen/somecity/testdestination
Have already reviewed a dozen other SO posts about 'post__not_in' but clearly I am missing something. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. Driving myself crazy trying to solve this hahaha  thanks for the help!

What does print_r( $params ); show? Is the post__not_in parameter getting the post ID of the current post?

Sidenote that the 'posts_per_page' should be a number, not a string

paged, post__not_in and posts_per_page all do not belong into the tax query, they belong on the same level as post_type.
